# NSURL with encoding

Tags: iphone, ios, nsurl

I have a this URL and I cannot seem to get the code below to work

In this code urlToGrab = http://192.1.1.233:8000/en-US/app/search/flashtimeline?auto_pause=true&q=search%20host%3D%22JRVIN-LT%22

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlToGrab];
[webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url]];
```

This code doesn't work. When setting breakpoints 'url'is null.  If I use "http://192.1.1.233:8000/en-US/app/search/flashtimeline?auto_pause=true&q=search" it will work.

Comment: Hello igervin...   i wrote like below code....but  i don't get null

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must URL-decode the string first. Example:

```
NSString * urlToGrab = [[@"http://192.1.1.233:8000/en-US/app/search/flashtimeline?auto_pause=true&q=search%20host%3D%22JRVIN-LT%22"
    stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"+" withString:@" "]
    stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlToGrab];
[webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url]];
```

Replacing "+" with " " is just in case you have another encoded URL that contains "+".

Answer (score 1):

i wrote like below code....but  i did't get null

```
NSString *str=[[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"http://192.1.1.233:8000/en-US/app/search/flashtimeline?auto_pause=true&q=search%20host%3D%22JRVIN-LT%22"];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:str];
```

Comment: The question is not whether OP gets null or not. Btw there is nothing called null in Objective-C, it's nil.

The question is why the webView does not load the URL correctly.

Answer (score 0):

should be:

```
NSString * urlToGrab = [[@"yourURL"
stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"+" withString:@" "]
stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

not "stringByReplacingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding"